# CentOS, Can I install 5.10 rpm into 5.8?

Tags: rpm, patch

I heard that bash-3.2-33.el5_10.4 is a CVE-7169 patch for CentOS 5.
So I found an announcement from CentOS website below.
http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2014-September/020594.html

Now I'm wondering,
According to below description, bash-3.2.-33.el5_10.4 is for CentOS 5.10.
Then, is that OK if I install bash-3.2.-33.el5_10.4 into CentOS 5.8??

==========================================================
Note:  The above RPMS, built with the ".el5_10" dist tag are built
against CentoS-5.10 for CentOS-5.10.  The source code was not modified,
but the packages in the build root are the current CentOS-5.10 packages.

There is also a set of packages built against the upcoming CentOS-5.11
with a ".el5_11" dist tag that will be an upgrade when 5.11 is released
and all the packages in that build root are from the upcoming
CentOS-5.11 release.  The ".el5_11" announcement and package will be
done as a zero-day update to CentOS-5.11.

We wanted to get the Important bash update out for 5.10 while also
getting the proper packages out for 5.11 as well, so this was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly a .el5_10 or .el5_11 binary bash rpm will
install on a .el5_8 box.

Try-and-see by doing
    cd /tmp
    rpm2cpio bash*.rpm |cpio -dim
and then try to run bash
    cd /tmp
    ./bin/bash

If you can execute bash, then you can try to install
the package:
    rpm -Uvh bash*.rpm

Worst that happens is that the upgrade will fail for other reasons.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. However, I'm not curious just about this rpm. As you know, CVE-7169 is critical problems, so I think there should be every type of CentOS versions. But there is only one rpm file for CentOS 5.10. Why is that? Here is CVE-2014-7169 patch links. http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2014-September/020591.html